# How do I move the fingers?

Tags: modeling, animation

I'm so new with Blender. How can I move the fingers ? Because when I'm trying to move only one finger, every finger moves.

[image]

Comment: hello, if you don't know how it works, maybe begin with the basics, i.e. how bones work, how to rig, inverse kinematics, etc...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a **weight paint** issue, like if every bone controls all the finger. Check [this quick tutorial (youtube)](https://youtu.be/Tl4qTgwQwYw) to see how weight painting works and try to fix it by yourself.